# cakephp 2.5.1: Inflector::slug

Tags: cakephp

I am using this for slugging:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->Link(__('more'), '/l/'. Inflector::slug($data['Object']['region']) .'/'. Inflector::slug($data['Object']['cat']) .'/'. Inflector::slug($data['Object']['title']) .'/'. $data['Object']['id'], array('class' => 'regular_btn'));?>
```

to get nice SEO friendly links. 
Works fine so far, the result looks like

> .../l/reg/cat/Postmodern_luxury_residence_close_to_Real_Bendinat_golf_course/123

I just wished that the _ could be a - instead? 
Is that possible to change?

Thanks!!

Comment: Just take a look at the docs: **http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Inflector.html#_slug**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be simply

```
Inflector::slug($data['Object']['region'], '-')
```

http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-Inflector.html#_slug